# Write to s3 bucket directly using Spark/Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I am trying to write parquet file in the s3 bucket in Spark/scala program but not sure what's the best way to do it. After a bit of research, I found below option :

Add below dependency in the code :

```
 "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.11.690",
 "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-aws" % "2.6.0"
```

then, set the required config in the code :

```
  spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.access.key", "access key")
    // Replace Key with your AWS secret key (You can find this on IAM
    spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", "secrete key")
    spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "end point", "us-east-1")
```

But, I am getting below error :

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Request ID...
```

I am inclined to go with above option as this would give me flexibility to directly write the file to S3:

```
jdbcWriteDF.write.format("parquet")
        .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
        .save("s3a://cs-dev/cmc_site_qa.parquet")
```

With the AWSClient option, I need to generate it first on my local and then upload it on the S3 bucket.

I know the keys are correct as when I was using in one of my jave process, it was working fine..

```
 AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(s3BucketAccessKey, s3BucketSecretKey)))
                .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(s3BucketEndpoint, "us-east-1"))
                .build();

          return s3client;
```